# How to calculate shipping costs for a multi-vendor in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, calculation

How to calculate shipping costs for a multi-vendor in Python?

Here is data in my cart:

```
cart =  {"line1" : {'vendor1': 1.2,'shipping_cost': 10000,'city': "Manchester",},
         "line2" :  {'vendor2': 2,'shipping_cost': 20000,'city': "Liverpool",},
         "line3" : {'vendor1': 1.2,'shipping_cost': 10000,'city': "Manchester",},
         "line4" :  {'vendor2': 3,'shipping_cost': 20000,'city': "Liverpool",},
}
```

I want to calculate shipping cost by vendor as below:

```
(vendor1 + vendor1) *  shipping_cost = 2.4 * 10.000 = 24.000
(vendor2 + vendor2) *  shipping_cost = 5 * 20.000 = 100.000
```

How to achieve this calculation in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary to store the cost.
you can get the vendor key for this dictionary and assign the total cost for the value.

```py
cart =  {"line1" : {'vendor1': 1.2,'shipping_cost': 10000,'city': "Manchester",},
         "line2" :  {'vendor2': 2,'shipping_cost': 20000,'city': "Liverpool",},
         "line3" : {'vendor1': 1.2,'shipping_cost': 10000,'city': "Manchester",},
         "line4" :  {'vendor2': 3,'shipping_cost': 20000,'city': "Liverpool",},
}

cost = {}
for sale in cart.values():
    vendor = [key for key in sale.keys() if 'vendor' in key][0]
    if vendor in cost.keys():
        cost[vendor] += sale['shipping_cost']*sale[vendor]
    else:
        cost[vendor] = sale['shipping_cost']*sale[vendor]
print(cost)
```